# javascript .print() - turn off default printer

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-config

Out system uses the javascript .print(), which brings up the print dialog with the default printer selected.  Is there a way to turn off the default printer so that when the dialog appears there is no printer selected so that the user has to select one.

I was hoping to use a global setting (e.g. web.config) so I could switch the default printer on or off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple answer. No.

You cannot and will never be able to access (let alone modify) system settings through JavaScript.