# Get printer status in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using window.print() to print my page.
But I want get status of printer like out of page.
How can I do that using angular 2 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31978682/2622292

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node JS - Use Printer (Hardware)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977475/node-js-use-printer-hardware)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can access system settings (which may include print status) such as connected printers through JS web applications. Security etc. Please see

[javascript .print() - turn off default printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590642/javascript-print-turn-off-default-printer)

Comment: can i do it using node js? Its also javascript but still if any way is there

Comment: You should be able to yes, I think you can find certain node packages which allow you to do this. Direct js through the browser, no but via node I think it i possible. See the link below, it may be what you're looking for. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipp