# Can I define print driver in a javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, printing

The only (un)helpful answer I've found on SO so far is this - [javascript .print() - turn off default printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590642/javascript-print-turn-off-default-printer) but I wanted to clarify for my sake as I'm working in a more controlled environment, and that question is very old.

We have a web-based internal system for managing product data, and this will only ever be accessed on Windows 10 PC's, through Chrome browser, and by a few certain users.  I want to add a Print button into this system, but most specifically, I want it to use Chrome's built in "Save to PDF" driver every time for this website.  I'm not worried whether users can change this in print settings or not, I just want this to be the default.  I don't want to make this printer the default for the whole computer however, only when printing from this system.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Tomalak's answer in the linked post still stands.

Comment: Maybe write a Windows application?

Comment: @Teemu I didn't know if further developments had made this possible since then, and also thought that in a controlled environment there may be a feasible workaround - Aluan's comment is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you can't get access to the printer driver from JS. That will never change. Imagine any arbitrary website being able to change the print settings of a user without his knowledge. This will never be allowed.

However, if it is an internal system, write a chrome extension for your users.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/printerProvider